# Funcion de Ventana sumar o restar registros anteriores - SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo el siguiente Script

```
DECLARE @SaldoPrincipal NUMERIC(18,2) = 6146.43

SELECT 
 Orden
,Fecha
,Debito
,Credito

FROM Tabla
Where Cuenta = '02548752'
```

El cual me arroja el siguiente resultado

```
Orden   Fecha          Debito     Credito   
1     2023-09-30    0.00           6.48 
2     2023-09-12    0.00           6109.38  
3     2023-09-01    0.00           0.03 
4     2023-08-22    15.00          0.00 
5     2023-08-07    55.00          0.00 
6     2023-08-01    0.00           0.17 
7     2023-07-01    0.00           0.09 
8     2023-06-15    0.00           100.00   
9     2023-05-19    20.00          0.00 
10    2023-05-08    50.00          0.00 
11    2023-05-01    55.00          0.00 
12    2023-05-01    50.00          0.00 
13    2023-05-01    0.00           2.28 
14    2023-04-20    2000.00        0.00 
15    2023-04-19    4000.00        0.00 
16    2023-04-13    0.00           6109.38  
17    2023-04-01    0.00           6.34 
18    2023-03-24    4100.00        0.00 
19    2023-03-23    8010.00        0.00 
20    2023-03-17    100.00         0.00 
21    2023-03-14    0.00           2.24 
22    2023-03-14    0.00           12218.76
23    2023-03-01    0.00           0.01 
24    2023-02-17    105.00         0.00 
25    2023-02-15    0.00           110.00
```

Quiero agregar un campo llamado Saldo el cual en el primero registro me coloque unicamente el saldo de la variable que tengo declarada arriba, y a partir de la segunda fila, me vaya Restando si es Credito o Sumando si es Debito (si yo se que es alreves pero asi lo necesito)

Estoy intentando hacerlo mediante una funcion de Ventana, comparto script

```
DECLARE @SaldoPrincipal NUMERIC(18,2) = 6146.43

SELECT 
 Orden
,Fecha
,Debito
,Credito
,CASE
     WHEN Orden = 1 THEN @SaldoPrincipal
     ELSE 
          CASE 
               WHEN Debito > 0 THEN @SaldoPrincipal + LAG(Debito,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY orden)
               WHEN Credito > 0 THEN @SaldoPrincipal - LAG(Credito,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY orden)
          END 
       
 END AS Saldo

FROM Tabla
Where Cuenta = '02548752'
```

Sin embargo, con esto obtengo el resultado que quiero pero hasta cierta fila, no completamente

Comparto el resultado que me arroja

```
Orden   Fecha      Debito      Credito       Saldo
1   2023-09-30      0.00        6.48       6146.43
2   2023-09-12      0.00        6109.38    6139.95
3   2023-09-01      0.00        0.03       37.05
4   2023-08-22      15.00       0.00       6146.43
5   2023-08-07      55.00       0.00       6161.43
6   2023-08-01      0.00        0.17       6146.43
7   2023-07-01      0.00        0.09       6146.26
8   2023-06-15      0.00        100.00     6146.34
9   2023-05-19      20.00       0.00       6146.43
10  2023-05-08      50.00       0.00       6166.43
11  2023-05-01      55.00       0.00       6196.43
12  2023-05-01      50.00       0.00       6201.43
13  2023-05-01      0.00        2.28       6146.43
14  2023-04-20      2000.00     0.00       6146.43
15  2023-04-19      4000.00     0.00       8146.43
16  2023-04-13      0.00        6109.38    6146.43
17  2023-04-01      0.00        6.34       37.05
18  2023-03-24      4100.00     0.00       6146.43
19  2023-03-23      8010.00     0.00       10246.43
20  2023-03-17      100.00      0.00       14156.43
21  2023-03-14      0.00        2.24       6146.43
22  2023-03-14      0.00        12218.76    6144.19
23  2023-03-01      0.00        0.01       -6072.33
24  2023-02-17      105.00      0.00       6146.43
25  2023-02-15      0.00        110.00     6146.43
```

Y este es el resultado que quiero

```
Orden   Fecha      Debito      Credito       Saldo
1   2023-09-30      0.00        6.48       6146.43
2   2023-09-12      0.00        6109.38    6139.95
3   2023-09-01      0.00        0.03       30.57
4   2023-08-22      15.00       0.00       30.54
5   2023-08-07      55.00       0.00       45.54
6   2023-08-01      0.00        0.17       100.54
7   2023-07-01      0.00        0.09       100.37
8   2023-06-15      0.00        100.00     100.28
9   2023-05-19      20.00       0.00       0.28
10  2023-05-08      50.00       0.00       20.28
11  2023-05-01      55.00       0.00       70.28
12  2023-05-01      50.00       0.00       125.28
13  2023-05-01      0.00        2.28       175.28
14  2023-04-20      2000.00     0.00       173.00
15  2023-04-19      4000.00     0.00       2173.00
16  2023-04-13      0.00        6109.38    6173.00
17  2023-04-01      0.00        6.34       63.62
18  2023-03-24      4100.00     0.00       57.28
19  2023-03-23      8010.00     0.00       4157.28
20  2023-03-17      100.00      0.00       12167.28
21  2023-03-14      0.00        2.24       12267.28
22  2023-03-14      0.00        12218.76   12265.04
23  2023-03-01      0.00        0.01       46.28
24  2023-02-17      105.00      0.00       46.27
25  2023-02-15      0.00        110.00     151.27
```

Estoy utilizando SQL con SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres llevar un total acumulado de tus filas, necesitas usar SUM() y no solo LAG() que solo tomará un dato. Además estás comparando el valor actual para decidir cual valor previo tomar.

Al final de cuentas, el código se puede simplificar bastante.

```
DECLARE @SaldoPrincipal NUMERIC(18,2) = 6146.43

SELECT 
     Orden
    ,Fecha
    ,Debito
    ,Credito
    -- Incluimos el saldo principal y hacemos una suma de (débito positivo y crédito en negativo)
    -- Le decimos que tome el orden de la columna orden y tome las filas desde el incio hasta la anterior.
    ,@SaldoPrincipal + ISNULL( SUM(Debito - Credito) OVER(ORDER BY orden ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS Saldo
FROM Tabla
Where Cuenta = '02548752';
```